# R xmlParse() Indexing

Tags: xml, r

I have data generated from `xmlParse()`. I am able to obtain a reference to an XMLNode called `root`

```
> class(root)
[1] "XMLInternalElementNode" "XMLInternalNode"        "XMLAbstractNode"
```

When, I do

```
> root[[2]][[1]]
<tr class="party-republican race-winner"><th rowspan="5" class="results-county">Autauga <span class="precincts-reporting">100.0% Reporting</span></th>&#13;
                                &#13;
                                <th scope="row" class="results-candidate">M. Romney</th>&#13;
                                <td class="results-party"><abbr title="Republican">GOP</abbr></td>&#13;
                                <td class="results-percentage">72.6%</td>&#13;
                                <td class="results-popular">    17,366</td>&#13;
                            </tr>
```

I try to reference the value in side the tag:

```
<td class="results-percentage">
```

However doing `root[[1]][[2]][["<td class='results-percentage'>]]` returns null

What am I doing wrong that prevents me from accessing the 72.6% value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give a valid `xpath`, Something like this :

```
  //td[@class='results-percentage'] ## preeceeding by td and cotaining a certain class
```

Using your data:

```
library(XML)
dd <- xmlParse('<tr class="party-republican race-winner"><th rowspan="5" class="results-county">Autauga <span class="precincts-reporting">100.0% Reporting</span></th>&#13;
  &#13;
  <th scope="row" class="results-candidate">M. Romney</th>&#13;
  <td class="results-party"><abbr title="Republican">GOP</abbr></td>&#13;
  <td class="results-percentage">72.6%</td>&#13;
  <td class="results-popular">    17,366</td>&#13;
  </tr> ',asText=TRUE)
```

Then applying xpath

```
getNodeSet(dd, "//td[@class='results-percentage']/text()")[[1]]
72.6%
```

Or using `xpathSApply`:

```
xpathSApply(dd, "//td[@class='results-percentage']",xmlValue)
[1] "72.6%"
```

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for. What does "/text()" do? I understand that without it you get the tag and value, but why does /text() remove the tag?

Comment: Okay, I believe I know what it does. Is it a term for "match any text value one level deeper"?